# What do I do after this?

Tags: arithmetic

The question goes..

In a recent marathon, $\frac{1}{10}$ of the participants finished in less than $3$ hours. $\frac{1}{3}$ of the remaining participants finished in $4$ hours or less. Out of those who took more than $4$ hours, twice as many finished in $5$ hours or less as finished in more than $5$ hours. If $650$ people took more than $5$ hours to finish the marathon, how many people participated in the event?

I got 
$(650)2$ for finish in $5$ hours $= 1300$. 
$650$ people for more than $5$ hours..

And then I'm stuck because I don't know where to apply the 
$\frac{1}{10}$ for $3$ hours.
And $\frac{1}{3}$ of the remaining in $4$ hours.. 
$\frac{1}{3}$ of $\frac{9}{10}$?

Comment: Do I still add the other 650 for the people who finished in more than 5 hours to 1300? So 1950?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to think of $\frac{1}{3}$ of $\frac{9}{10}$. Let's go through the problem and calculate the actual fraction of participants in each cutoff. First we are given $\frac{1}{10}$ finish in the first $3$ hours. Then $\frac{1}{3}$ of the remainder finished in under $5$ hours  - that is $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{9}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$ finished in this period. Finally, twice as many people finished in the second to last group as in the last group. What is that in a fraction form? Let's call the number who finished in the last group $x$. We have $1-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{3}{10}=\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}$ of the participants remaining. Hence to find $x$, we just need to solve $x+2x=\frac{3}{5}$, so we have $x=\frac{1}{5}$. This leads to the conclusion that $650$ was $\frac{1}{5}$ of the participants, so the total number of participants was $650\times 5=3250$.

Alternatively, we could proceed from where you left off - having found $650$ in the last group and $1300$ in the second to last group. We know that $\frac{1}{10}$ of the total were in the first group and then $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{9}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$ were in the second group. So in the first two groups combined, there were $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{3}{10}=\frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{5}$ of the participants. Hence the total number of people you have found so far account for the other $\frac{3}{5}$ of participants. Hence the total number of participants would be $(650+1300)\times\frac{5}{3}=3250$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just wondering where did you get the 1 in the equation 1- 1/10 - 3/10...

Comment: @Ardine The $1$ stands for the total number of people who participated, so I'm taking the fraction of people who we have accounted for away from the total. Another way to think about it is that all the fractions of people in each group should add up to $1$.

Comment: @Ardine Glad to help :)